# google maps api-v2 xamarin

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to add a map to my application but it simply wont work...

I have enabled the android maps api in google apis console, got my sha1 fingerprint, both debug and release using the following scripts:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

and:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "D:\Software Projects\xxx.keystore"                -alias TasteiTClient  -storepass xxx -keypass xxx
```

generated keys for both using the sha1 fingerpring

added them both to the app manifest:

```
<application android:label="TasteIT!" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" android:icon="@drawable/appicon">
    <!--        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
               android:value="ReleaseKey"/>-->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="DebugKey" />
</application>
```

and added the mapfragment to the layout:

```
 <fragment
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:id="@+id/RestaurantsMap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and I am still getting the following errors once the layout with the map is displayed:

```
[Google Maps Android API] Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
[Google Maps Android API] Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

Can anyone spot what I did wrong?

Thanks

Amit

Answer (score 0):

Figured it our...
My package name had mixed casing @#!#$@!$... :)